# search uppercase and lowercase words in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a PHP file which will search in txt file and will display the result.

However, if the word is written with uppercase text and the user searches for the same word with lowercase the PHP file will show found no matches1

for example:

I have Apple Juice in the txt file.
the user searches for apple juice.
the PHP shows no matches found as it is looking for the exact same word "Apple Juice" which has uppercase in it.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head><title>some title</title></head>
<body>

<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['search'])) {
    $file = 'mytxtfile.txt';
    $searchfor = '';
    // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $searchfor = $_POST['search'];
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    $fullword = '\b\Q' . $w . '\E\b';
    $regex = '/' . $fullword . '(?!.*' . $fullword . ')/i';
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
    if(preg_match_all("/\b([a-z]+[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*|[A-Z]+[a-z]+[a-zA-Z]*)\b/", $pattern, $contents, $matches)){
       echo "Population: \n";
       echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);

    }
    else{
       echo "No matches found";
    }
    header('Content-Type: text/html');
    }
?>

  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

i did try and added this `if(preg_match_all("/\b([a-z]+[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*|[A-Z]+[a-z]+[a-zA-Z]*)\b/",` to my code but that didn't work!

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just lowercase the whole thing regardless. This way its case insensitive. Otherwise there is a `i` flag you can add to regexp to make them case insensitive

Comment: `$contents = strtolower(file_get_contents($file));`

Comment: I know this is unrelated to your question, however I'm curious; does your code work without getting a warning message like this `headers already sent`?

Comment: @Fred, indeed it does work.

Comment: Do what @CP510 said. Just wrap the search in strtolower and then it will be easy. Don't make things hard.

Comment: @SimonPresto That is so strange. I tested it and I'm getting that error. Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Fred there is no redirection here

Comment: @Fred You could give the 'ol `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` a try for that header problem.

Comment: Also theres no reason to have the HTML parts on the top, move them to after the PHP and presto, no header problem.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I know, and that's what I found strange while testing it on my hosted server.

Comment: @CP510, that will work as long as the user doesn't search with uppercase i.e. some users turn the caps on on their keyboard and if that happens then the result will not be shown again!

Comment: @CP510 That I knew (HTML parts). However, even with the other question the OP posted earlier, I was also getting that error. Most bizarre. Ok, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @SimonPresto Actually, a way around this is to use `strtoupper` then `strtolower` your string. Works for me for another script I have. That way, even if they enter mixed case etc., everything will turn out in lowercase.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Feel free to edit it peeps.

Comment: The headers problem is because you're outputting some HTML before sending them. Headers are the first thing that need to be in the output, before any other text (even spaces give troubles here). You can use ob_start() (output buffering enabled) at the beginning of the file to avoid instant output in any script, but it would be better to re-arrange the script.

Comment: @AlejandroIván Yes, CP510 noted that for me. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the adjusted source. This sets the search string and the file contents to lowercase. I also moved the HTML headers down and initiated the output buffer during the search logic.

```
<?php
ob_start();
if(!empty($_POST['search'])) {
$file = 'mytxtfile.txt';
$searchfor = '';
// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$searchfor = strtolower($_POST['search']); #LOWER CASE THE SEARCH STRING TO
$contents = strtolower(file_get_contents($file)); #MAIN ADDITION TO MAKE IT LOWER CASE
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$fullword = '\b\Q' . $w . '\E\b';
$regex = '/' . $fullword . '(?!.*' . $fullword . ')/i';
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all("/\b([a-z]+[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*|[A-Z]+[a-z]+[a-zA-Z]*)\b/", $pattern,             $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Population: \n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);

}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
header('Content-Type: text/html');
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
<html>
<head><title>some title</title></head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works beautifully, however and it's not your code that's at fault, I keep getting a `No matches found`. But good work, +1 here on my part. Cheers

Comment: as I stated this works as long as the user don't have the caps on!

Comment: I edited the code to set the input and file contents to both be lower case. So it should be completely case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex pattern like this:

```
// The "i" at the end is to make a case-insensitive search
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/mi";
```